# In querying a collection in a Mongo database with Mongoose, how can I find where a value is LIKE a query term?

Tags: regex, string, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've search hard for an answer to this but haven't found anything that works. I have a NodeJS app, with the Mongoose ORM. I'm trying to query my Mongo database where a result is LIKE the query.

I have tried using a new RegExp to find the results, but it hasn't worked for me. The only time I get a result is when the query is exactly the same as the collection property's value.

Here's what I'm using right now:

```
    var query = "Some Query String.";    
    var q = new RegExp('^/.*'+ query +'.*/i$');

    Quote.find({author: q}, function(err, doc){
        cb(doc);
    });
```

If the value of an author property contains something LIKE the query (for instance: 'some. query String'), I need to return the results. Perhaps stripping case, and excluding special characters is all I can do? What is the best way to do this? My RegEx in this example is obviously not working. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to add an example of a `query` string and a doc `author` property value that's not matching when you expect it to?

Comment: Just updated the question. Let me know if it doesn't make sense. Thanks!

Comment: You probably want `new RegExp(query, 'i');`.  You don't include the `/` chars when using `RegExp`.  But this won't exclude special characters like you seem to want.

Comment: That did it, my friend! Is there a RegExp way to allow a query to match with or without the periods? You're the best! If you post your reply as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to create your RegExp as follows instead as you don't include the `/` chars when using `new RegExp`:

```
var q = new RegExp(query, 'i');
```

I don't know of a way to ignore periods in the `author` properties of your docs with a RegExp though.  You may want to look at [`$text`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) queries for more flexible searching like that.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again! Worked like a charm.